# How interact between PublishSubject and PublishProcessor to simulate deliveries?

Tags: java-8, functional-programming, rx-java, reactive-programming

How interact between PublishSubject and PublishProcessor  to simulate deliveries?

I have this problem:
I have a list of Orders
Receive the orders filter by temp hot, cook the order,
Place the order on the hot shelf, after that a courier will deliver the orders every 3 seconds.
If the shelf is full discard the orders in the shelf.

Hot shelf  ->   Size: 10

I tried use PublishSubject to send to a PublishProcessor that will be the hot shelf
but that does not work?
Any idea about how to achieve that?
I do not have to much experience with reactive programming.

```
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.BackpressureOverflowStrategy;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.processors.PublishProcessor;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.schedulers.Schedulers;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.subjects.PublishSubject;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class App{
        public static void main( String[] args ){
                ReadJson read = new ReadJson();
                List<Order> list = read.cargarArchivoJson("orders.json");
                PublishSubject<Order> subjectOrder = PublishSubject.create();
                PublishProcessor<Order> hotShelf = PublishProcessor.create();
                AtomicInteger hotSize = new AtomicInteger(0);
               
                subjectOrder.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                        .filter(r -> r.getTemp().equals("hot"))
                        .subscribe(
                        s -> {
                                hotSize.set(hotSize.get() + 1);
                                System.out.println("Sent to hot Shelf, Size: " + hotSize.get());
                                hotShelf.onNext(s);
                        },
                        Throwable::printStackTrace,
                        () -> System.out.println("--- Processed all Hot Temperature Orders")
                );

                hotShelf.onBackpressureBuffer(10, () ->{ System.out.println("dropping the oldest .. ");  }, BackpressureOverflowStrategy.DROP_OLDEST)
                        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                        .subscribe(s -> {
                                System.out.println("Waiting for the courier..");
                                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
                                hotSize.set(hotSize.get() - 1);
                                System.out.println("Hot Order delivered, Size on hot Shelf: " + hotSize.get());
                        }, Throwable::printStackTrace);


                for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                        subjectOrder.onNext(list.get(i));
                }
        }
}
```

the output is:
Sent to hot Shelf, Size: 1
Sent to hot Shelf, Size: 2
Sent to hot Shelf, Size: 3
Sent to hot Shelf, Size: 4
Sent to hot Shelf, Size: 5
Sent to hot Shelf, Size: 6
Waiting for the courier..
Sent to hot Shelf, Size: 7
Sent to hot Shelf, Size: 8
Sent to hot Shelf, Size: 9
..

It finished when the loop to iterate the list ends and it didn't deliver a single order.

**Udpate:**
Now is working but the problem it does not discard after 10, it does after a large amount, how would be the best way to discard a Order because using a atomic inteteger is not the best way of do this also beacuse  I want to  know the id of the discarded order.
Is there a way to end the program once the hotShelf ends? to avoid a while loop or a Thread.sleep().

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
                ReadJson read = new ReadJson();
                List<Order> list = read.cargarArchivoJson("orders.json");
                Subject<Order> subjectOrder = (Order)PublishSubject.create().toSerialized();
                PublishProcessor<Order> hotShelf = PublishProcessor.create();
                AtomicInteger hotSize = new AtomicInteger(0);

                subjectOrder.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                        .filter(r -> r.getTemp().equals("hot"))
                        .subscribe(
                        s -> {
                                hotSize.set(hotSize.get() + 1);
                                System.out.println("Sent to hot Shelf, Size: " + hotSize.get());
                                hotShelf.onNext(s);
                        },
                        Throwable::printStackTrace,
                        () -> System.out.println("--- Processed all Hot Temperature Orders")
                );

                hotShelf.onBackpressureBuffer(10, () ->{ System.out.println("dropping the oldest .. ");  hotSize.set(hotSize.get() -1); }, BackpressureOverflowStrategy.DROP_OLDEST)
                        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                        .subscribe(s -> {
                                System.out.println("Waiting for the courier..");
                                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
                                hotSize.set(hotSize.get() - 1);
                                System.out.println("Hot Order delivered, Size on hot Shelf: " + hotSize.get());
                        }, Throwable::printStackTrace);


                for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                        subjectOrder.onNext(list.get(i));
                }
                
                subjectOrder.onComplete();
                boolean flag;
                while(!hotShelf.hasComplete()){
                flag = false; // just for test to avoid an error on a empty while
            }
        }
```

Comment: For one, the main method has to wait for the async bits to be able to finish; so you'll need to `Thread.sleep` at the end. Second, you have a data race with `hotSize`: there is a non-atomic increment and decrement that may overwrite each other's amounts. Third, because of the buffer-drop-oldest, `hotSize` would increment beyond 10 as the dropped items can't decrement it back.

Comment: @akarnokd , ok do you now how will be the best way to handle with the discard  of the orders? I guess this way using atomic is not the best way of do this.

Comment: Use `hotSize.getAndIncrement()` for the addition and `hotSize.decrementAndGet()` in the  `onBackpressurBuffer`'s callback and in the `subscribe` method.

Comment: @akarnokd thanks for the advices, one more thing there is a way to implement a custom BackpressureOverflowStrategy to select a item based on  a internal order variable, because a reserched on the web, the documentation and I  did not find information about that, I asked because you seem to have some experience I was reading your blog and it constains useful information.

Comment: Not with the standard operator. You'd have to write one from scratch. For example, you could take the [standard implementation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/3.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/rxjava3/internal/operators/flowable/FlowableOnBackpressureBufferStrategy.java#L105-L129) by source and modify the logic that decides what item to drop.